# How to get the name of each element of a list using lapply()?

Tags: r, lapply

Imagine that I have the following list

```
> test <- list("a" = 1, "b" = 2)
```

Each element of the list has a name :

```
> names(test)
```

Now, I want to extract that name using `lapply()` because I want to use it in a new function which will be called using lapply. I just don't know how to extract the name of each element.

I've tried using `deparse()` and `substitute()` but the outcome is weird :

```
> lapply(test, function(x) {deparse(substitute(x))})
$a
[1] "X[[i]]"

$b
[1] "X[[i]]"
```

Does anyone has a clue ?

### Precision :

I want to do something like this : 
I have a list which is like test :

```
> test <- list("a" = matrix(1, ncol = 3), "b" = matrix(2, ncol = 3))
```

I want to apply a function to that list which transform the data inside each element and give a specific name for each column :

```
make_df <- function(x) {
  output <- data.frame(x)
  names(output) <- c("items", "type", NAME_OF_X)
  return(output)
}
lapply(test, make_df)
```

The expected output is :

```
> test
$a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
attr(,"names")
[1] "index" "type"  "a"    

$b
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    2    2
attr(,"names")
[1] "index" "type"  "b"
```

I don't know how I can get the name of the element to give a name to my third column.

Comment: Try with `lapply(names(test), function(x) test[[x]])`  By looping with `names`, you have the option to get the value as well as the key

Comment: or `lapply(seq_along(test), function(i) names(test[i]))`

Comment: Ok, the second one works but I want something which works with the list, not  `seq_along()`

Comment: @PAC I showed the way to get the value, but if you only need the key `lapply(names(test), function(x) x)`

Comment: @akrun Why is my question a duplicate ?

Comment: You wanted to get the names of the list elements and the link looks like a duplicate of what you wanted

Comment: @akrun My question is now more precise

Comment: For the first list element, you have a single column and for second 3 columns.  Can you show the expected output?  Or did you meant `ncol=3` in place of `nrow=3`?

Comment: Ok, I've corrected myself

Comment: Try `make_df <- function(x){
 setNames(as.data.frame(test[[x]]), c('items', 'type', x))};
 lapply(names(test), make_df)`

Comment: Now, I saw the expected output. But your code is changing the `matrix` to `data.frame` and in the expected output, you still have a matrix with attribute as names. I am confused now.

Comment: For the updated expected output `lapply(names(test), function(x) {x1 <- test[[x]];attr(x1, 'names') <- c('items', 'type',x);x1})`

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to have a different description and expected output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a solution using `purrr`. It seems to run faster than the solution by aaronwolden but slower than akrun's solution (if that's important):

```
library(purrr)
map2(test, names(test), function(vec, name) {
    names(vec) <- c("index", "type", name)
    return(vec)
})

$a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
attr(,"names")
[1] "index" "type"  "a"    

$b
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    2    2
attr(,"names")
[1] "index" "type"  "b"
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you meant for both elements of `test` to contain a 3-columned matrix, you can use `mapply()` and provide separately the list and the list's names:

```
  test <- list("a" = matrix(1, ncol = 3), "b" = matrix(2, ncol = 3))

  make_df <- function(x, y) {
    output <- data.frame(x)
    names(output) <- c("items", "type", y)
    return(output)
  }

  mapply(make_df, x = test, y = names(test), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

which produces:

```
## $a
##   items type a
## 1     1    1 1
##
## $b
##   items type b
## 1     2    2 2
```

**Update**

To achieve the expected output you describe in your updated question:

```
test.names <- lapply(names(test), function(x) c("index", "type", x))
Map(setNames, test, test.names)
```

produces:

```
## $a
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    1    1
## attr(,"names")
## [1] "a"     "index" "type"  
## 
## $b
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    2    2    2
## attr(,"names")
## [1] "b"     "index" "type"
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the expected output showed

```
  make_attr_names <- function(x){
   x1 <- test[[x]]
   attr(x1, 'names') <- c('items','type', x)
   x1}
lapply(names(test), make_attr_names)  
 #[[1]]
 #    [,1] [,2] [,3]
 #[1,]    1    1    1
 #attr(,"names")
 #[1] "items" "type"  "a"    

 #[[2]]
 #    [,1] [,2] [,3]
 #[1,]    2    2    2
 #attr(,"names")
 #[1] "items" "type"  "b"
```

Or based on the description

```
 make_df <- function(x){
       setNames(as.data.frame(test[[x]]), c('items', 'type', x))}
 lapply(names(test), make_df)
 #[[1]]
 # items type a
 #1     1    1 1

 #[[2]]
 #  items type b
 #1     2    2 2
```